# Is it possible to group images by drawing lines on it in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiimageview

For an example if i have multiple images on views in random position. Images are selected by drawing lines on it and group images by using gestures. Right now i can able to show images randomly but not able group images by drawing line on it.
Here screenshot 1 is result which i have getting now: [image]

screenshot 2 which is exactly what i want. [image]

Comment: Just about anything is possible. And this sure sounds like it is too. Look up “drawing paths” when you learn how to create a path you could reference every imageView that shares a coordinate with the path

Comment: Thanks @Jake is there any sample code for this can you share. i have struggling for past week.

Comment: I don’t. I’ve never done it. But conceptually that’s what I would try.

Comment: You can check if the gesture of user belong to the image frame, get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are trying to do I would start by creating a custom view (a subclass) that is able to handle gestures and draw paths.

For gesture recognizer I would use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. What you do is have an array of points where the gesture was handled which are then used to draw the path:

```
private var currentPathPoints: [CGPoint] = []
@objc private func onPan(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began: currentPathPoints = [sender.location(in: self)] // Reset current array by only showing a current point. User just started his path
    case .changed: currentPathPoints.append(sender.location(in: self)) // Just append a new point
    case .cancelled, .ended: endPath() // Will need to report that user lifted his finger
    default: break // These extra states are her just to annoy us
    }
}
```

So if this method is used by pan gesture recognizer it should track points where user is dragging. Now these are best drawn in `drawRect` which needs to be overridden in your view like:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    // Generate path
    let path: UIBezierPath = {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        var pointsToDistribute = currentPathPoints
        if let first = pointsToDistribute.first {
            path.move(to: first)
            pointsToDistribute.remove(at: 0)
        }
        pointsToDistribute.forEach { point in
            path.addLine(to: point)
        }
        return path
    }()

    let color = UIColor.red // TODO: user your true color

    color.setStroke()
    path.lineWidth = 3.0
    path.stroke()
}
```

Now this method will be called when you invalidate drawing by calling `setNeedsDisplay`. In your case that is best done on setter of your path points:

```
private var currentPathPoints: [CGPoint] = [] {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Since this view should be as an overlay to your whole scene you need some way to reporting the events back. A delegate procedure should be created that implements methods like:

```
func endPath() {
    delegate?.myLineView(self, finishedPath: currentPathPoints)
}
```

So now if view controller is a delegate it can check which image views were selected within the path. For first version it should be enough to just check if any of the points is within any of the image views:

```
func myLineView(sender: MyLineView, finishedPath pathPoints: [CGPoint]) {
    let convertedPoints: [CGPoint] = pathPoints.map { sender.convert($0, to: viewThatContainsImages) }

    let imageViewsHitByPath = allImageViews.filter { imageView in
       return convertedPoints.contains(where: { imageView.frame.contains($0) })
    }

// Use imageViewsHitByPath
}
```

Now after this basic implementation you can start playing by drawing a nicer line (curved) and with cases where you don't check if a point is inside image view but rather if a line between any 2 neighbor points intersects your image view.